# How to get address by user's id oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

In my project, front end needs, following JSON data with this format. So I Created two table for user and their addresses,

```
{
   "data":{
      "user":{
         "cif":"102345678",
         "username":"user_00002",
         "fname":"Kevin",
         "lname":"",
         "contactDetails":{
            "permanentAddress":{
               "Line1":"no 1",
               "Line2":"cross lane",
               "city":"dilhi"
            },
            "correspondenceAddress":{
               "Line1":"no 2",
               "Line2":"main street",
               "city":"dilhi"
            },
            "mobile":"32323",
            "email":"tets1@.com"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So I plan to going with this table structure,

**USER_TABLE**

```
+------------+-------+-------+------------+--------+
| USERNAME   | FNAME | LNAME | EMAIL      | MOBILE |
+------------+-------+-------+------------+--------+
| user_00002 | Jhone | sean  | tets1@.com | 32323  |
+------------+-------+-------+------------+--------+
| user_00003 | Kevin | Niga  | tets2@.com | 23232  |
+------------+-------+-------+------------+--------+
| user_00005 | Mal   | Ruvaw | tets3@.com | 34343  |
+------------+-------+-------+------------+--------+
```

**USER_ADDRESS**

```
+------------+----------------+-------+-------------+----------+
| USERNAME   | ADDRESS_TYPE   | LINE1 | LINE2       | CITY     |
+------------+----------------+-------+-------------+----------+
| user_00002 | PERMANENT      | no 1  | cross lane  | dilhi    |
+------------+----------------+-------+-------------+----------+
| user_00002 | CORRESPONDENSE | no 2  | main street | dilhi    |
+------------+----------------+-------+-------------+----------+
| user_00003 | PERMANENT      | no 33 | cross lane  | jakartha |
+------------+----------------+-------+-------------+----------+
| user_00003 | CORRESPONDENSE | no 35 | main street | jakartha |
+------------+----------------+-------+-------------+----------+
```

Address table I created this way because, each user have two addresses, one is permanent and other one is correspondence. So is this good table structure to handle this? if yes, then I need to get following output from sql query, How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: So, what's your plan? You have the JSON input. Then you show us a table at the very end of your question, do you need to get THAT table from the JSON? That's easy. But then, you say your real plan is to have those two separate tables. Are you using the table at the end of your question as an intermediate (temporary) step, from which you will create the two distinct tables? Do you need help on that step too?

Comment: @mathguy In this project bit hilarious. our front end teams needs the above json data and they don't want to change it. So still database structure not created. so my plan is to create database table as above (USER_TABLE and USER_ADDRESS) I just want to verify that table structures is good or bad, as well as need some query to retrieve image showing table data.

Comment: The two-table structure is fine. The one-table structure you show at the end of your post is also fine, **assuming** that the "address type" can never be anything other than either "primary residence" or "correspondence address". If the address type can vary - and, critically, if it may only be known from the data - then the problem is more complicated, and the two-table arrangement is mandatory. (The two-table arrangement is fine in ALL cases, but mandatory if the address type may vary and may only be known from the data.)

Comment: To generate two tables from the JSON input, you can either have a temporary table to unwind the JSON data to the single-table output you show at the end of your question, and then generate the data for the two tables from this single, temporary table. Or, you can populate both tables directly from the JSON, but that requires parsing the JSON twice. If you have a lot of data, then the choice may matter. If you don't, parsing the JSON twice may be the simpler choice. So, what do you expect to be your real-life case?

Comment: Unless... am I misunderstanding the question? Perhaps: You will create the database, you will have those two tables, they will contain data, and THEN you want to know how to generate the JSON from the table data? If so, then that's a simple application of JSON functions, but the answer will depend critically on your Oracle version. What version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my experience, Your table structure seems correct to me. You can try pivoting the address table first and then join the table with user_table -

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_TABLE U
  JOIN (SELECT USERNAME,
               MAX(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_TYPE = 'PERMANENT' THEN LINE1 ELSE NULL END) PR_LINE1,
               MAX(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_TYPE = 'PERMANENT' THEN LINE2 ELSE NULL END) PR_LINE2,
               MAX(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_TYPE = 'PERMANENT' THEN CITY ELSE NULL END) PR_CITY,
               MAX(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_TYPE = 'CORRESPONDENSE' THEN LINE1 ELSE NULL END) COR_LINE1,
               MAX(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_TYPE = 'CORRESPONDENSE' THEN LINE2 ELSE NULL END) COR_LINE2,
               MAX(CASE WHEN ADDRESS_TYPE = 'CORRESPONDENSE' THEN CITY ELSE NULL END) COR_CITY
          FROM USER_ADDRESS
         GROUP BY USERNAME) AD ON U.USERNAME = AD.USERNAME;
```

Comment: It's still not entirely clear to me if the OP needs to generate the table data from JSON, or to generate the JSON from the table data; but one way or another, I don't expect the answer to have nothing related to JSON in it.